# How to use am vs ab?

Tags: preposition, standard-german, swiss-standard-german

The course will begin from the 1st Jan.

> Der Kurs beginnt am 1. Januar.
> Der Kurs beginnt ab dem ersten Januar.

Can we interchangeably use *am* and *ab* to show the beginning of something on certain month and date?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are talking about a moment, use *»an dem« = »am«* (in Englisch: *at the*).
If you are talking about a period of time, that begins at a certain moment, use *»ab dem«* (in Englisch: *from the*).

The beginning of a period of time is not a period of time by itself. It is a moment. So, when you use the verb *»beginnen«,* you talk about a moment and so you have to use *»am«.* This means: your first sentence is correct, the second is wrong.

If you want to talk about a period of time, you have to use another verb like *»stattfinden«* (to take place) for example, in Austria it is then said:

> Der Kurs **findet** ab dem ersten Jänner **statt.**

Comment: Ich bin ja sehr für die Erhaltung der Vielfalt der deutschen Sprache, aber ist es wirklich nötig, das Beispiel eines Anfängers vom deutschen Standarddeutsch zum österreichischen Standarddeutsch zu verändern?

Comment: @Roland ich stimme dir zu, aber zur Verteidigung Huberts: _Jänner_ ist so standardsprachlich unmarkiert, dass es überhaupt nicht dialektal wahrgenommen wird und es einem Österreicher vermutlich gar nicht auffällt, dass der Ausdruck nicht dem deutschen Standard entspricht. (Also es kann passieren, dass "Januar" gelesen und automatisch unbewusst "Jänner" geschrieben wurde.)

Comment: @phipsgabler "in Austria it is then said" deutet aber nicht darauf hin. (Ich bin nicht dagegen, auf Sprachunterschiede zwischen D, A und CH hinzuweisen. Ich wünsche mir nur, dies nicht auf Kosten des Verständnisses von Anfängern zu tun.)

Comment: Finde ich auch, aber das hat auch jemand anderer reineditiert.

Comment: Oh, sorry. Das habe ich nicht gesehen.

Comment: @phipsgabler - ich wollte Huberts Antwort nicht durch einen weiteren D/CH Besipielsatz erweitern, im Beispiel nicht  `Jänner` durch `Januar` ersetzen und habe das vorhandene Beispiel zur Eindeutigkeit A zugeordnet. Einfach `Jänner` durch `Januar` zu ersetzen wäre auch in Bezug auf die Frage klarer gewesen. Vielleicht holt das ja Hubert nach und löscht meinen Zusatz wieder.

Comment: @Roland: Als ich den Beispielsatz geschrieben habe, habe ich jenes Wort verwendet, das dort wo ich lebe das einzige ist, das für das erste Monat im Jahr in Verwendung ist.  Ich habe einfach nicht daran gedacht, das hierzulande praktisch nie verwendete Wort *Januar* zu benutzen. Niemand in Österreich (von deutschen Immigranten und Touristen abgesehen) verwendet in Österreich das Wort *»Januar«.* Der Hinweis »in Austria« stammt nicht von mir. Den hat ein gewisser »help-info.de« hinterher und ohne meine Kenntnis hineineditiert. Ich finde es aber gut, dass das jetzt da steht, das schafft Klarheit.

Comment: @phipsgabler: Das Wort »Jänner« wird in Österreich nicht als dialektal wahrgenommen, weil es kein Dialektwort ist. Es ist in Österreich ganz einfach das einzige Wort, das als Name für das erste Monat eines Jahres verwendet wird. Es steht in jedem Kalender der in Österreich hergestellt wird. Auch in dem Kalender auf meinem Computer steht »Jänner«. Ebenso heißt in österreichischen Schulbüchern und Gesetzestexten das erste Monat immer »Jänner«. Monatszeitschriften haben eine Jänner-Ausgabe, Nachrichtensprecher und Politiker kündigen an, dass irgendwas ab 1. Jänner gilt usw.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Das mag ja alles sein. Aber wenn die Fragestellerin das Wort "Jänner" in einem Beispiel verwendet und die Frage mit einem Österreich-Tag versieht, sollte man dies nicht zu "Januar" ändern, oder? Hier verwendet sie das Wort "Januar"  und einen Schweiz-Tag.